# Navigation on one site using href="#About us" does not work on smaller devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, responsive-design

In my django project, I am trying to build a menu for navigation on one single site. The navigation should be done by `href="#about us"` The menu has three sizes, one for big screens (PC), one for medium screens (Tablets), and one for small screens (Phones). The navigation works on PC size menu, but does not work on the other ones. To be clear, all of the menus redirects the user to something like `mywebsite.com/info#about us`, but just the PC menu actually scrolls the site. There, I fill the menus with some content from a database:

```
{% block big-menu %}
    {% for faq in question_list %}
      <a href="#{{faq.question}}" class="w3-button w3-bar-item w3-hover-text-blue">{{faq.question}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block small-menu %}
    {% for faq in question_list %}
      <a href="#{{faq.question}}" class="w3-button w3-bar-item w3-hover-text-blue">{{faq.question}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And there is the template for the menus:

```
  <div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-collapse w3-card w3-animate-right w3-hide-small" style="width:300px;right:0;top:0;" id="mySidebar">
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_close()"><h3>Menu &times;</h3></button>
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-large w3-hide-small w3-hide-medium"><h3>Menu</h3></a>
    {% block big-menu %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

  <div class="w3-bar-block w3-collapse w3-animate-right w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium w3-light-gray" style="display:none;" id="smallSidebar">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-large"><h3>Menu</h3></a>
    {% block small-menu %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
```

And there I assign ids to content I am linking to in the menu:

```
 <div class="w3-hide-small w3-hide-medium"style="width: calc(100% - 300px);">
  {% for faq in question_list %}
        <div class="w3-card-4" id="{{faq.question}}">
        <h3 class="w3-container w3-blue">{{faq.question}}</h3>
        <div class="w3-container">
        {{faq.answer}}
        </div>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>

  <div class="w3-hide-large">
  {% for faq in question_list %}
        <div class="w3-card-4" id="{{faq.question}}">
        <h3 class="w3-container w3-blue">{{faq.question}}</h3>
        <div class="w3-container">
        {{faq.answer}}
        </div>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

There are screenshots of working & not working menu:

[image: Working menu on PC]

[image: Not working menu on phone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by two elements (the big content and the small one) having the same id (`{{faq.question}}`). So, the fix is as following:

```
{% block big-menu %}
    {% for faq in question_list %}
      <a href="#{{faq.question}}big" class="w3-button w3-bar-item w3-hover-text-blue">{{faq.question}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block small-menu %}
    {% for faq in question_list %}
      <a href="#{{faq.question}}" class="w3-button w3-bar-item w3-hover-text-blue">{{faq.question}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <h1>Vitosoft - FAQ</h1>

  <div class="w3-hide-small w3-hide-medium"style="width: calc(100% - 300px);">
  {% for faq in question_list %}
        <div class="w3-card-4" id="{{faq.question}}big">
        <h3 class="w3-container w3-blue">{{faq.question}}</h3>
        <div class="w3-container">
        {{faq.answer}}
        </div>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>

  <div class="w3-hide-large">
  {% for faq in question_list %}
        <div class="w3-card-4" id="{{faq.question}}">
        <h3 class="w3-container w3-blue">{{faq.question}}</h3>
        <div class="w3-container">
        {{faq.answer}}
        </div>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A jquery script will do it, try the following:

```
$("a").on('click', function(event) {
     # Distinguish the a tags with others by adding a class, like $('a.anchor').click
     if (this.hash !== "") {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behavior of the link
        var hash = this.hash;

        $('html, body').animate({ # With just a smooth animation within 800 miliseconds, we scroll towards the target anchor
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top // we scroll 
            }, 800, function(){

            // window.location.hash = hash; // Optional here
            // this will return the part of the URL that follows the # symbol, including the # symbol.
        });
     } // End if
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! I never worked with jquery before, can you please explain your code a bit more? And can you also tell me where to place this script, please?

Comment: I did in comments, put it inside a tag script or a seperate js file, make sure that your jquery js is right above this script

Comment: I implemented your script into my code, but when I click on one of the links in the menu, nothing happens. I see following error in the google chrome console: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #I%20have%20a%20question.%20What%20shell%20I%20do?
    at Function.oe.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at oe.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at oe.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.oe [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at new w.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2) ... ` The #I%20have%20a%20question ... part depends on what I click on.